# メソッドAの返り値をテストする際にメソッドA内にあるメソッドBの返り値をモック化したい。

Tags: flutter, dart, mockito

### 環境

flutter
dart
mockito

*****やりたいこととできないこと*****
現在、 メソッドAの返り値をテストする際にメソッドA内にあるメソッドBの返り値をモック化しようとしています。
一応、メソッドA内で実行されるメソッドBの返り値を引数にすればモック化せずにテストできるのですが、既存のコードを変更してしまうためこの解決策はやりたくないです。

### コード

```dart
// sample.dart
class Sample {
  int a (){
    return b() + 4;
  }

  int b (){
    return 3;
    // 普通は７
    // mock化のテストなら9になるはず
  }
}
```

```dart
// sample_test.dart

import 'package:sellca_pad_3/models/sample.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/annotations.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import 'sample_test.mocks.dart';

@GenerateMocks([Sample])
void main(){
  test('モックのテスト', (){
    final mockSample = MockSample();
    when(mockSample.b()).thenReturn(5);
    final sample = Sample();
    final addResult = sample.a();
    expect(addResult, 9);
  });
}
```

*****このテストの結果の期待値と実際の値*****

期待値: 9
実際の値: 7

`when(mockSample.b()).thenReturn(5);` でメソッドbの返り値を3から5に変更し、これでメソッドaの返り値の値がメソッドbの返り値(3)+4から、メソッドbをモック化した返り値(5)+4で9になるようにしたかったのですが、これではモック化していないメソッドbがメソッドa内で実行されてしまうので、返り値が7になってしまいます。
この問題を解決するために何かアドバイスがあればお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

ご提示したコードは不完全だと思いますが、見たところご提示したコードはモックの機能を入れましたが、利用していないです。

とても簡単な話です、このコードで新しいSampleのインスタンスを作成したです、このインスタンスはモックと完全に関係ないインスタンスです。

```
final sample = Sample();
```